# Pass a full-row as an argument in a cell located on that same row?

Tags: google-sheets

I want to pass a full row (eg. 3:3 or such) to a function from a certain cell. The problem is that this cell is located on that same row so i get an "Circular dependency detected" error.

Is there a good way of solving this? For instance passing a row excluding a certain cell or passing "rest of the row" or something like that?

I suppose I could use a onEdit function and listen to changes on any of the cells on that row but I'm wondering if there's a more straight forward way. And I dislike having to hardcode cell-positions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple syntax for "rest of the row". Suppose that your special cell is `B3` and you want the sum of the cells in the "rest of the row", i.e., `C3`, `D3`, `E3`, ...

```
B3: =sum( C3:3 )
```

As you can see, `C3:3` is very similar to the `3:3` syntax you are already familiar with; the difference is simply that it starts the range with column C instead of column A.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Thank you.
Actually I did try that but I just assumed it didn't work because it doesn't show a box around the selected cells like it does with specific cells or even full-rows/columns?